# Generating WADL with Jersey rest

Tags: jersey, wadl

I'd like to stop jersey generating wadl for one of my jersey resources. Does anyone know if this is  possible to do with annotations or web.xml configuration.

Thanks,
SAm.

Answer (score 3):

as from latest jersey [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html#d0e11125):

> WADL generation is enabled in Jersey by default. This means that
>   OPTIONS methods are added by default to each resource and an
>   auto-generated /application.wadl resource is deployed too. To override
>   this default behavior and disable WADL generation in Jersey, setup the
>   configuration property in your application:

```
jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl=true
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@mSolujic's answer is correct, but Jersey/Spring users may need something slightly different for their web.xml (at least with Jersey 1.19):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```